# C# Console App Executed by SQL Agent

Tags: c#, sql, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am trying to run a .cs (console Application) which uses EPPLUS to move an Oracle table to an excel document. I am using the SQL agent to schedule this process but have just recieved an error

> Message Executed as user: WIN2016-SFD-02\SYSTEM. Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EPPlus, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.     at
>   OracletoExcel.Program.Main(String[] args).  Process Exit Code
>   -532462766.  The step failed.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: this could be 1 of 2 things `1` you added a using in the header but not the references itself or `2 you need to add both the using in the header as well as manually in the references and make sure the `CopyLocal=` property is set to `true`

Comment: in my case i used a repository and git didnt push nugets so i had to add the untracked file dll